# Spring - class path resource X cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: spring, maven, resources

I have a problem that I cannot solve! I have googled hours and hours but I don't find any solution...
I have this :

[consumerContext.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOejy.png)

and a file that loads this xml resource (consumerContext.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...>

<!-- Inclusion d'autres fichiers de contexte Spring -->
<import resource="classpath:/org/example/demo/ticket/consumer/consumerContext.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:/org/example/demo/ticket/business/businessContext.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:/org/example/demo/ticket/webapp/webappContext.xml" />

</beans>
```

I'm am using using Maven and src/main/resources is in the classpath.

I have always and always the error :

```
class path resource [org/example/demo/ticket/consumer/consumerContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Do anyone has an idea?

Thanks per advance (and sorry for my english...)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that you dont put consumerContext.xml at org/example/demo/ticket/consumer/.

To fix it:

1)Put consumerContext.xml and other xml's directly in src/resources

2) change

```
<import resource="classpath:/org/example/demo/ticket/consumer/consumerContext.xml" />
```

to

```
<import resource="classpath:consumerContext.xml" />
```